# convert Curl to php

Tags: php, curl

Is it possible to convert this curl command to PHP?

```
curl -H "cwauth-token: CwEqP_oQXCiDKt3ph0leZ2AlKsqE6E4N " "https://reports.voluum.com/report?from=2014-09-24T00%3A00%3A00Z&to=2014-0925T00%3A00%3A00Z&tz=Europe%2FWarsaw&sort=visits&direction=desc&columns=campa ignName&columns=visits&columns=clicks&columns=conversions&columns=revenue&co lumns=cost&columns=profit&columns=cpv&columns=ctr&columns=cr&columns=cv&colu mns=roi&columns=epv&columns=epc&columns=ap&columns=errors&groupBy=campaign&o ffset=0&limit=100&include=active"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the fish:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://reports.voluum.com/report?from=2014-09-24T00%3A00%3A00Z&to=2014-0925T00%3A00%3A00Z&tz=Europe%2FWarsaw&sort=visits&direction=desc&columns=campa ignName&columns=visits&columns=clicks&columns=conversions&columns=revenue&co lumns=cost&columns=profit&columns=cpv&columns=ctr&columns=cr&columns=cv&colu mns=roi&columns=epv&columns=epc&columns=ap&columns=errors&groupBy=campaign&o ffset=0&limit=100&include=active");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Cwauth-Token: CwEqP_oQXCiDKt3ph0leZ2AlKsqE6E4N";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

Here's how to fish:
https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

And here's a few fishing machines you can use:
http://curl.trillworks.com/#php
https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/

And BTW, here's why you should consider fishing alternatives:

- [Requests for PHP](http://requests.ryanmccue.info)
- [Guzzle, PHP HTTP Client](http://docs.guzzlephp.org)